# 2 different encodings of text in 1 file[C]

Tags: c, encoding

Good  *news* day everone
I perform the learning task, it's work with In/Out text to the file. In general, the point of the program is :

1. Open the file
2. definition of the encoding(In test file i have ANSI, UTF-8, UTF-16)
3. Parsing the text
4. Output of results to the file.

To work with text i use char and wchar_t types and function `WideCharToMultiByte()`. The problem is that If Input file have  Output `UTF-8` or `UTF-16` encoding, than Output file have 2 different encodings.

### The first part is result of copyng text from Input file.

Reading Input file

```
while (!feof(file)) 
{
    w = getwc(file);    
    wch_buffer[i] = w;  
    i++;
}
```

Converting to char

```
size = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wch_buffer, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);    
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wch_buffer, -1, result, size, NULL, NULL);
```

And adding to the Output file

```
fputs(ch_buffer, OutPut);
```

### And second part is text that has been added by the parser. In both cases there are cyrillic symbols.

somthing like that

```
fprintf(OutPut,"\nОшибка. На строке %d обнаружен повторное открытие тега",Line);
```

Then i open Output file in *Notepad++* and change encoding. After that Only 1 part of text readable(Latin symbols readable in both parts). By the way in the console, everything is all right.
IDE VS2012

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOb7p.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP7NG.png

2 images show what hapened if change encoding in *Notepad++*

### The problem is 2 encoding in 1 file, part of text not readable.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a question... what is it that troubles you? What is your problem? Can you post some code example? By posting your question like this sounds more like spam.

Comment: Edit that, hope to become clearer